# c# How to get all user's login session

Tags: c#, session

I have "User Info" session for a login user, in an IIS ASP.NET site.

For now I can access it like this:

```cs
// Login
User userinfo=new User(); //An entity store login user info.
// some stuff ...
HttpContext.Current.Session["UserInfo"] = userinfo; //Save to session


// Get session
User user=HttpContext.Current.Session["UserInfo"] as User;
// get user info or something ...
```

That's get one single user, what if I want to get all login user's "UserInfo" session ?

Had search on this site, but got answer ware outdated.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: What is your authentication system? ASP.Net Identity?

Comment: Yes it's asp.net, I'll update it on question.

Comment: there is a lot of asp.net authentication systems. Are we talking about [ASP.Net Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity) specificly? (it is literally named `ASP.Net Identity`)

Comment: Don't think there's a built in way to do that, you can save logged in status in the db for each user and pull information that way.